# Unexpected maven directories

Tags: maven, path, java-home, system-variable

I've just downloaded Maven 3.0.4.

My variables are:

`M2_HOME  C:\Program Files (x86)\apache-maven-3.0.4`
`JAVA_HOME C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_35`

and my PATH

`C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\OEM\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\OEM\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\OEM\12.0\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Roxio\OEM\AudioCore\;%FRASCATI_HOME%/bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%M2_HOME%\bin`

I get this error when not on maven directory:

```
C:\Users\rmescalera>mvn -version
"mvn" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.
```

and this other from maven directory:

`ERROR: M2_HOME is set to an invalid directory. M2_HOME = "C:\Program Files (x86)\apache-maven-3.0.4\bin" Please set the M2_HOME variable in your environment to match the location of the Maven installation`

The point is in the maven [webpage](http://maven.apache.org/download.html#Installation) it says to set %MAVEN_HOME%\bin in the PATH but when I download and extract the zip, this is the structure I get:

[image: maven directories]

So, obviously there is no bin directory in apache-maven-3.0.4!

I have tried copying only what's inside 
`C:\Program Files (x86)\apache-maven-3.0.4\apache-maven\src`
into a new `C:/maven directory and setting the right variables`

What's wrong? And what's up with this directory structure I get? Where should my variables point at?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems you have dowloaded the maven source code. Download from [here](http://maven.apache.org/download.html). Make sure you are downloading [(Binary zip)](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/maven/maven-3/3.0.4/binaries/apache-maven-3.0.4-bin.zip)

Comment: thx basiljames and @kothvandir, i've done so. I get the right structure now, but still getting the same error: M2_HOME is set to an invalid directory, no matter what directory a invoke mvn -version from. I've tried moving straight into to C:\maven and all the above too!

Comment: Problem solved. I only had to delete the User Variable that I had created following the maven installation instructions. Afeter downloading and installing the binary zip and deleting that variable everything worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You've downloaded the source tar/zip of maven, if you want to use that release you have to compile it before.
Download the [binary distribution](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/maven/maven-3/3.0.4/binaries/apache-maven-3.0.4-bin.tar.gz) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem installing maven 3.1.1.
The reason was that i had also an older version of maven 2.0.4 in the path variable, before my %M2_HOME%\bin

I removed the older one from the PATH and it works.